# Problema de contexto entre classes

Tags: android, android-fragment

Na linha 93 do "menu1_Fragment" aparece o seguinte erro: "**StreamingMediaPlayer (android.Content.Context, ImageButton) in StreamingMediaPlayer cannot be applied to (player.kmk.com.kmk.menu1_Fragment, ImageButton)**". Sim, a intenção é usar o mesmo playButton em determinado contexto, mas não entendi o problema.

*menu1_Fragment.java:*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;


public class menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;
    private boolean isPlaying;
    private ImageButton playButton;
    private String urlStreaming;
    private menu1_Fragment station;

    public menu1_Fragment(){}


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        //   listen.ouvir();
        //    listen.definirVolumeSlider();
        Bundle bundle;
        this.urlStreaming = "http://sh.upx.com.br:10369";

        playButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.play_button);

        this.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView)
            {
                if (isPlaying)
                {
                    audioStreamer.interrupt();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
                if (!isPlaying)
                {
                    startStreamingAudio();
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
                isPlaying=!isPlaying;
            }
        });

        this.audioManager = (AudioManager)(getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE));
        int i = this.audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
        int j = this.audioManager.getStreamVolume(3);
        getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(3);
        SeekBar localSeekBar = (SeekBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        localSeekBar.setMax(i);
        localSeekBar.setProgress(j);
        localSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar, int paramAnonymousInt, boolean paramAnonymousBoolean)
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(3, paramAnonymousInt, 0);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
            {
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar paramAnonymousSeekBar)
            {
            }
        });
        return rootview;


    }



    private void startStreamingAudio()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.audioStreamer != null)
                this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
            this.audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, playButton);
            this.audioStreamer.startStreaming(this.urlStreaming, 5208L, 216L);
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException localIOException)
        {
            while (true)
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", localIOException);
        }
    }



    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (this.audioStreamer != null)
            this.audioStreamer.interrupt();
    }

}
```

*StreamingMediaPlayer.java*

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/**
 * MediaPlayer does not yet support streaming from external URLs so this class provides a pseudo-streaming function
 * by downloading the content incrementally & playing as soon as we get enough audio in our temporary storage.
 */
public class StreamingMediaPlayer {

    private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER =  96*10/8;//assume 96kbps*10secs/8bits per byte

    private ImageButton playButton;

    private ProgressDialog connecting;

    //  Track for display by progressBar
    private long mediaLengthInKb, mediaLengthInSeconds;
    private int totalKbRead = 0;

    // Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private MediaPlayer     mediaPlayer;

    private File downloadingMediaFile;

    private boolean isInterrupted;

    private Context context;

    private int counter = 0;

    public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context,ImageButton    playButton)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.playButton = playButton;
        this.connecting = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Conectando...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface)
            {
                StreamingMediaPlayer.this.connecting.dismiss();
                StreamingMediaPlayer.this.interrupt();
            }
        });
        this.connecting.setCancelable(true);
    }

    /**
     * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
     */
    public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long  mediaLengthInKb, long   mediaLengthInSeconds) throws IOException {

        this.mediaLengthInKb = mediaLengthInKb;
        this.mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaLengthInSeconds;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=" + mediaUrl, e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    /**
     * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the setDataSource
     * for that local file
     */
    public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

        URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
        }

        downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia.dat");

        // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or something, we also delete any previously
        // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh.  If you use this code, always delete
        // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk memory.  Of course, you can also
        // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for instant replay if you wanted as well.
        if (downloadingMediaFile.exists()) {
            downloadingMediaFile.delete();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
        byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
        int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            totalBytesRead += numread;
            incrementalBytesRead += numread;
            totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

            testMediaBuffer();
            fireDataLoadUpdate();
        } while (validateNotInterrupted());
        stream.close();
        if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
            fireDataFullyLoaded();
        }
    }

    private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {
        if (isInterrupted) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                //mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
     * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
     */
    private void  testMediaBuffer() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                    if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                        try {
                            startMediaPlayer();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);
                        }
                    }
                } else if ( mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 ){
                    //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                    //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                    //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
                    transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    private void startMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");

            // We double buffer the data to avoid potential read/write errors that could happen if the
            // download thread attempted to write at the same time the MediaPlayer was trying to read.
            // For example, we can't guarantee that the MediaPlayer won't open a file for playing and leave it locked while
            // the media is playing.  This would permanently deadlock the file download.  To avoid such a deadloack,
            // we move the currently loaded data to a temporary buffer file that we start playing while the remaining
            // data downloads.
            moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

            Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length()+"");

            mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);

            // We have pre-loaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so update the buttons & progress meters.
            mediaPlayer.start();
            startPlayProgressUpdater();
            playButton.setEnabled(true);
            this.connecting.dismiss();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.", e);
            return;
        }
    }

    private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile)
            throws IOException {
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what +") with extra (" +extra +")" );
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        //  It appears that for security/permission reasons, it is better to pass a FileDescriptor rather than a direct path to the File.
        //  Also I have seen errors such as "PVMFErrNotSupported" and "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" if a file path String is passed to
        //  setDataSource().  So unless otherwise noted, we use a FileDescriptor here.
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        return mPlayer;
    }

    /**
     * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
     * NOTE: Interacting with a MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so
     * this method should always be called using a Handler.
     */
    private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            // First determine if we need to restart the player after transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
            boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.  Store the old File for deleting later.
            File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
            File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");

            //  This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on exit.  If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything.  If you want to
            // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write caching code and please send me a copy.
            bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();
            moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

            // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start a new one.  So far (Android v1.5),
            // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've stopped the player and started a new one
            mediaPlayer.pause();

            // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior one.
            mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

            //  Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was previously playing.
            //  NOTE:  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
            //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
            boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
            if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

            // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no longer needed.
            oldBufferedFile.delete();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);
        }
    }

    private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                float loadProgress = ((float)totalKbRead/(float)mediaLengthInKb);
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

                // Delete the downloaded File as it's now been transferred to the currently playing buffer file.
                downloadingMediaFile.delete();
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayer;
    }

    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        float progress = (((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/1000)/mediaLengthInSeconds);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }
    }

    public void interrupt() {
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
        isInterrupted = true;
        validateNotInterrupted();
    }

    /**
     *  Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
     */
    public void moveFile(File   oldLocation, File   newLocation)
            throws IOException {

        if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
            BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
            BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
            try {
                byte[]  buff = new byte[8192];
                int numChars;
                while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                    writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
                }
            } catch( IOException ex ) {
                throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
            } finally {
                try {
                    if ( reader != null ){
                        writer.close();
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch( IOException ex ){
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O construtor da classe `StreamingMediaPlayer` requer um objeto `Context`. No Android, `Activities` são exemplos de contextos válidos. No caso do seu fragmento, o contexto, ou seja a Activity que contém esse fragmento, é obtida através do método `getActivity()`. Portanto você deve fazer assim:

```
this.audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(getActivity(), playButton);
```